# My d3-geo project only displays points, not the map itself

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, geojson, topojson

I am working on creating a visualization to display data for various cities on a map. I currently have the points showing up in the designated area, but the map itself does not appear (even in the HTML).

[Here is what appears after page load.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYQCD.png) This is the HTML generated by the code below:

```
<svg data-v-ecb69b0a="" data-v-0e3cd57e="" width="960" height="600">

  <g class="cities">

    <path d="M921.9017045647397,486.52310787494935m0,4.5a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,-9a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,9z"></path>

    <path d="M900.5084921592315,208.78382629852422m0,4.5a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,-9a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,9z"></path>

    <path d="M960,113.47689212505065m0,4.5a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,-9a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,9z"></path>

    <path d="M-1.8189894035458565e-12,307.52970151278714m0,4.5a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,-9a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,9z"></path>

  </g>

</svg>
```

I am implementing this chart using Vue.js. Here is my Vue component source code:

```
<template>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import { feature } from 'topojson-client'

export default {
props: {chartData: {
  required: true
  }
},
data() {
  return {
    data: null
  }
},
watch: {
  chartData(val) {
    this.data = val;

    const projection = d3.geoEqualEarth();
    const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

    projection.fitSize(["960","600"], feature(this.data, this.data.objects.cities));

    const svg = d3.select("svg");

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "cities")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(feature(this.data, this.data.objects.cities).features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path);
  }
}
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

It is added to the app.vue file using:

```
<geographic-chart
  :chart-data="formattedGeoData"
></geographic-chart>
```

The formattedGeoData is in the following format:

```
{
"type": "Topology",
  "objects": {
  "type": "Geometry Collection",
    "geometries": [
      {
        "type": "Point",
        "id": "1",
        "coordinates": [41.2565, 95.9345]
      },
      {
        "type": "Point",
        "id": "2",
        "coordinates": [41.5868, 93.6250]
      },
      {
        "type": "Point",
        "id": "3",
        "coordinates": [41.8781, 87.6298]
      },
      {
        "type": "Point",
        "id": "4",
        "coordinates": [39.0997, 94.5786]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: With topojson.feature you need to specify the property of objects that contains your features (as objects could include both states and counties, or countries and land masses), eg: `data.objects.states` not `data.objects`

Comment: Here's an example of my new topojson:

"objects": {
      "cities": {
        "type": "GeometryCollection",
        "geometries": [
          {
            "type": "Point",
            "id": "1",
            "coordinates": [41.2565, 95.9345]
          }
        ]
      }
    }

When I reference this using this.data.objects.cities, the map still does not appear.

I recognize your name from [this](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/b40c1f11fbc49998e67c493fd473c075), I was looking at it earlier, why does it not need a property specification?

Comment: It specifies the property `convert`: `aisp.objects.convert`, which would be `this.data.objects.cities` in your example, but I should seek a bit of clarification first: the points (cities) show up on the map ("points showing up in the designated area") but other features are not showing up on the map ("the map itself does not appear"). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sure thing. I am able to get the city points to display but only on an empty space. The map background does not load in.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I jumped the gun a bit seeing the code for cities, is it possible to show how you add the background and a snippet of the data source.

Comment: Hey Andrew, sorry about the delay. I've edited my source code to clarify the situation.

Comment: Looks like what it is supposed to be showing: your map's data is four points and four points are shown, what are you looking for to be shown in addition?

Comment: I want the Equal Earth Projection (or albersUsa ultimately) to be shown. Similar to [this](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html) but without the lines (I'll be adding in data once I get the projection figured out).

Comment: You should be able to take the us-states geojson in that example and display it the same as your geojson (`topojson.feature` produces geojson) of points, the projection is used when drawing the path. Your data however, isn't in the US (so you  won't see a background) for two reasons: first, you have latitude,longitude, geojson is longitude,latitude for each coordinate, and second, your longitudes should be negative.

Comment: (sorry I didn't see the latitude/longitude swap earlier - wasn't looking for it, didn't seem to be relevant at that time.)

Comment: Alright I've fixed the coordinates so they appear correct relative to one another, but the map doesn't appear in the background. I now understand that my path variable merely refers to a path generator, but I am still unsure of how to underlay the map itself so the points I've created make sense.

Comment: Actually, I think I may understand now. Now, I believe that my path or projection variables don't truly have a map behind it. So I need to draw in the map myself, as far as I understand.

Comment: So I've got it drawn, woohoo! However, I am having some issues with overlaying the points. They are the correct scale but slightly higher than they should be. Do you know of any documentation available for d3 geo? Their official docs aren't very helpful.

Comment: The coordinates in both data sources are projected the same way - if there is drift between coordinates in one layer and coordinates in another that should be represented the same but aren't, they have different underlying coordinates in the data: this can be caused by errors in the data (more likely) or datum drift (less likely, and of limited magnitude)